# Printing the size of the input and output of all the layers of a pretrained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, model, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I want to print the sizes of the inputs and outputs of all the layers of a pretrained model. I uae this pretrained model as `self.feature` in my `class`.

The print of this pretrained model is as follows:

```
TimeSformer(
  (model): VisionTransformer(
(dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(patch_embed): PatchEmbed(
  (proj): Conv2d(3, 768, kernel_size=(16, 16), stride=(16, 16))
)
(pos_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(time_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(blocks): ModuleList(  
  (0): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): Identity()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
  (1): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(  # *********
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True) # @@@@@@@
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): DropPath()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
.
.
.
.
.
.
  (11): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): DropPath()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
)
(norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True) 
(head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=400, bias=True)
```

)

This the the code of my class and my method for printing the size of layers:

```
class Class(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=False):
        super(Class, self).__init__()
        
        
        self.feature =TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  
                                           pretrained_model='path/to/the/weight.pyth')

def forward(self, x):
    for layer in self.feature:
        x = layer(x)
        print(x.size())
    return x
```

I'm using the following approach for printing

But I am facing this error:

```
TypeError: 'TimeSformer' object is not iterable
```

How can I print the sizes of all the layers?

Update:

using the Following code receives the error mentioned in the comment:

```
def forward(self, x, out_consp = False):
layers=list(self.featureExtractor.children())
for layer in layers:
    x = layer(x)
    print(x.size())
return x
```

Comment: What is the size of a layer? Have you considered that this is not a well defined concept?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy , The question is edited.

Comment: It's still not well defined. Many types of operations work on inputs of arbitrary size, like convolutions, pooling, etc. When they have to be coerced into a specific size, you usually have "adaptive" layers, like adaptive averaging pooling. That's why you can pass images of basically any arbitrary resolution into a ResNet. Maybe for a fixed-size model input, you have a better chance of solving your problem (e.g., with hooks as described in Hatem's answer below). But this still might not always make sense. For instance, some models might randomize intermediate representation sizes per batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hooks to print the shape of the input and the output of each layer. You can use this code to do what you want.

```
def hook_function(module, input, output):
    print(f'{module.name} :')
    print(module)
    #print(module)
    if isinstance(input[0], tuple):
        print('input shapes:')
        for elem in input[0]:
            print(elem.shape)
    else:
        print(f'input shape: {input[0].shape}')
    if isinstance(output, tuple):
        print('output shapes:')
        for elem in output:
            print(elem.shape)
    else:
        print(f'output shape: {output.shape}')
    print('')

def set_names(net):
    def recurs(net,parent_name=None):
        for name, mod in net.named_children():
            if parent_name is not None:
                name = '_'.join([parent_name, name])
            recurs(mod, name)
            setattr(mod,'name',name)
        
    recurs(net)
def print_shapes(network, dummy_input_shape, device='cuda', eval=True):
    network = network.to(device)
    if eval:
        network.eval()
    else:
        network.train()
        assert dummy_input_shape[0] > 1
    #print(network)
    dummy = torch.randn(dummy_input_shape, device=device)
    set_names(network)
    handles = []
    def attach_hooks(net):
        leaf_layers = 0
        for mod in net.children():
            leaf_layers += 1
            attach_hooks(mod)
        if leaf_layers == 0:
            handles.append(net.register_forward_hook(hook_function))
    attach_hooks(network)
    network(dummy) 
    # if needed
    for handle in handles:
        handle.remove()
```

Example:

```
network = TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  
                                           pretrained_model='path/to/the/weight.pyth')
# The behaviour of a forward function could be different during training
print_shapes(network,(1,3,224,224),'cpu', eval=True)
print_shapes(network,(2,3,224,224),'cpu', eval=False)
```

A snippet of the output includes a layer that is *defined* before 'temporal_norm1' layer in 'Block' module but called or executed later (norm1).

```
model_blocks_11_temporal_fc :
Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
input shape: torch.Size([2, 1568, 768])
output shape: torch.Size([2, 1568, 768])

model_blocks_11_norm1 :
LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
input shape: torch.Size([16, 197, 768])
output shape: torch.Size([16, 197, 768])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I face the following error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'in the last line of the hook_function.

Comment: @dtr43 I have updated my answer so that the function operates on tuples.

Comment: Many thanks. In fact I need that the name of each block and the name of each layer in the blocks to be printed out, too. Is it possible for you to apply them, too?

Comment: @dtr43 yes it is possible. I will do that modification today,

Comment: I will be grateful because I need it soon. Thanks again

Comment: @dtr43 I have updated my answer to print the parent's name.

Comment: @dtr43 Let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately in the result of your code, in each block, the layers before "temporal_norm1" cannot be seen.

Comment: @dtr43 Is this the source of the model? 
'https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer'

Comment: Yes that  is the source.

Comment: @dtr43 The output is correct, I have checked it myself. The order of the printed layers and sizes is the same order these layers are called in the forward function, not in the order in which they are defined. All the layers used in a block's forward function are printed. Please check the output again.

Comment: A snippet of the output includes a layer that is *defined* before 'temporal_norm1' but called or executed later (norm1).
```
model_blocks_11_temporal_fc :
Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
input shape: torch.Size([2, 1568, 768])
output shape: torch.Size([2, 1568, 768])

model_blocks_11_norm1 :
LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
input shape: torch.Size([16, 197, 768])
output shape: torch.Size([16, 197, 768])

```

Comment: @dtr43 'https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer/blob/a5ef29a7b7264baff199a30b3306ac27de901133/timesformer/models/vit.py#L139' norm layer and attention block are called at the end of the forward function; however, they were defined at the beginning (in the init function). That's why when you simply print the model, they appear at the beginning of the block, but when you trace the input, they are called at the end.